# MATLAB everything except last element

Tags: matlab, syntax

Is there a MATLAB shorthand for

```
v( 1:length(v)-1 ) % everything except last element
```

In Python, its

```
v[ :-1 ]
```

Does MATLAB have a similar shorthand?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
v(1:end-1)
```